# neural networks trying to understand cost function with respect to gradient

Tags: python, neural-network, derivative

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x, deriv=False):
    if deriv==True:
        return 1-sigmoid(x)

    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

X = np.array([[0.2]])
y = np.array([[1]])

np.random.seed(0)
w0 = np.random.normal(size=(1,1), scale=0.1)

for i in range(100):
    l0 = X
    l1 = sigmoid(l0.dot(w0)) # forward propagation

    error = y-l1 #now back propagation start
    delta1 = sigmoid(l1,True) #please read nr.1 bellow

    delta_error = error*sigmoid(l1,True) 

    w0+=l0.T.dot(delta_error)

print(l1)
```

I understand everything regarding forward propagation. Please note this is simple one hidden layer network with one input and one output and there is no bias needed for this process.

What I do not understand is following.

Nr1.

O.k. we get the error. This makes sense, completely. But I don't understand how derivative of sigmoid function works with respect to error function.
In my case, error function is y-l1, but I do not understand what sigmoid derivative function really explains... In this case it is obvious, if l1 is higher, error is lower... so why we don't just update weights with condition if value error is bigger or smaller from previous epoch? I checked derivative value and error value for each epoch and there seems to be some linearity between them. If error gets lower, so does derivative... I know I am missing something in this puzzle, however I don't understand it yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a mathematical (calculus) problem.

Comment: @ForceBru Thank you. But please consider someone may find solution or expose error written in code.

Comment: I removed the tag "neural network" as there is no neural net here, it is just logistic regression, and not (as claimed in the question) "one hidden layer neural network" - there are no hidden layers.

Comment: @lejlot I don't get you guys, wouldn't it be easier to just type down the solution? And I added neural network back. IT is a neural network. A primitive one, but it is...

Comment: a good explanation here : https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/

Comment: Dadep, thank you, I have already read that... I am still having problem understanding. Thank you.

Comment: @Makaroniiii - no, when you do not have hidden layers situation is qualitatively different, in particular there would be no way to do the heuristic you suggested for a hidden layer (as the "responsibiity" for the error dissolves across many weights).

Comment: @Makaroniiii, I don't get _you_: do you think we are some kind of super-powerful AI, for which answering any question is merely "typing down the solution" that is found in a matter of seconds??? BTW, [this online book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com) explains ANNs really well, in my opinion, you should definitely check it out.

Comment: @lejlot Please, O.K. whatever, you won...

Comment: @ForceBru. Thank you for suggestion of the book, I might really read it.

Comment: To be fair, I think it is a bit of a philosophical debate if logistic regression is a type of neural network and isn't worth pulling the tag off. If he is *going* for a one hidden layer ANN, and accidentally coded up LR, then I guess we found the problem in his code. If I am trying to write depth first search, tag a question as such, but accidentally write BFS; I wouldn't want someone removing my tag. I would want them to answer the question saying: "I found the problem: you wrote BFS not DFS!"